# Elasticsearch Full text queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have text to index , every word in this text has its time.

I would like to index this text so I will be able to do the following query: "find Word A near Word B"

What I need is:

1. be able to control the near distance
2. be able to get back the hits words with their time

I tried several indexing and querying methods, but no luck

Any Idea?

Comment: You should provide a few example docs and how you would want the results.